# Vs code installation issue?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Unable to install vs code showing status-code=409 kind= snap-change-cnflict massage=snaop "code" has"install snap" change in progress, plz guide for complete installation !

Answer (score 0):

That's a way too common issue. It is possible that you have enabled **automatic updates** from your Ubuntu Settings and you tried to install something while that process was running.

You could wait for it to finish the update (there are no visual clues whatsoever) or you could try to kill the `snapd` process.

The brutal soulution would be to reboot your system, run updates and then install VS Code.

```
sudo reboot
```

Then, when it's up and running again....

```
sudo snap refresh
sudo snap install code
```

Hope this helps.